# Stored procedure that takes in a dynamic number of joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am trying to build a stored procedure that takes in a dynamic number of tables and joins them.

```
SELECT a.Account
FROM Database.Accounts a
JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM Database.TableStrings WHERE Row = 1) b ON a.Account = b.Account
JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM Database.TableStrings WHERE Row = 2) c ON a.Account = c.Account
JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM Database.TableStrings WHERE Row = 3) d ON a.Account = d.Account
...
/*Where the number of joins is equal to COUNT(Table_Name) FROM Database.TableStrings*/
```

or

```
first = SELECT a.Account
        FROM Database.Accounts a
        JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM Database.TableStrings WHERE Row = 1) b ON a.Account = b.Account

second = SELECT a.Account
         FROM first a
         JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM Database.TableStrings WHERE Row = 2) b ON a.Account = b.Account
...
```

Below is an example of the tables and the expected output:

```
---Database.Accounts---
Account (Integer)
------------------------
111
222
333
444
555

---Database.TableStrings---
Table_Name (String):
------------------------
'Database.HasPhoneNumber'
'Database.HasEmail'
'Database.HasBankAccount'

---Database.HasPhoneNumber---
Account (Integer)
------------------------
111
444

---Database.HasEmail---
Account (Integer)
------------------------
111
222


---Database.HasBankAccount---
Account (Integer)
------------------------
111
222
555
```

With the example tables, the expected output would be Account 111.

I am having a hard time visualizing how to do this in a stored procedure, if it is even possible.

Comment: you will need to use `Dynamic SQL`. Check out `sp_executesql`

Comment: Based on your sample query, you don't really required `Dynamic SQL`.  A simple `JOIN` between `Accounts` and `TableStrings` will be able to give you the result

Comment: Hi Squirrel, I have updated my initial ask to be more clear. The joins are not to join the strings, but to join the content of the database that is in the strings. I am inexperienced with Dynamic SQL and the potential SQL injection issues which is why I am reaching out.

Comment: please include some sample data and the expected result

Comment: I have added sample data. I hope this helped clarify and didn't make it tougher :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may consider using recursive queries `(cte)` to handle the string concatenation. and run `sp_executesql` to execute generated sql string query

lets generate also your table aliases using `char()`

```
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max), @strSQLjoin nvarchar(max)

set @strSQL = 'SELECT a.Account
    FROM Database.Accounts a ';

set @strSQLjoin = '';


with cte as (
    select 'Database.PhoneNumbers' as TableStrings
    union all select 'Database.Emails'
    union all select 'Database.BankAccounts'
), cte2 as (
    select TableStrings, (char(row_number() over (order by TableStrings) + 97)) as tbl 
    from cte)
    select @strSQLjoin = coalesce(@strSQLjoin 
        + ' JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM '+TableStrings+') '+tbl+' ON a.Account = '+tbl+'.Account '
        ,' JOIN (SELECT Table_Name FROM '+TableStrings+') '+tbl+' ON a.Account = '+tbl+'.Account')      
    from cte2;

set @strSQL=@strSQL + @strSQLjoin;
print @strSQL
exec sp_executesql @strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Would this solution leave me open to SQL Injection, or would I be fine since there are no user inputted parameters?

Comment: @JoshG, this won't lead to sql injection since stored procedures are server based. see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection/

Comment: This won't lead to SQL injection if you trust the contents of the TableStrings table. If TableStrings comes from an untrusted source - the approach is prone to SQL injection

Comment: @shurik, as OP mentioned, tableString is from table `Database.TableStrings`

Comment: Yes, I understand, and most likely you are right and the approach is safe. Just saying that in an unlikely situation if the TableStrings table is populated from some public facing web form - there is a possibility of SQL injection.  So as long as you trust the content of the table  you are safe.

Comment: Thank you for the dialog that helped me in my understanding. My other question from this query:
What is the + 97 doing in the row number field?

Comment: acii 97 is small letter `a`

Comment: 1 for char() table aliases. There is a limitation though, you can only have 26 tables joined this way :) just kidding, hopefully it does not go that far

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is not exactly what you asked for. But since adding new rows to the TableStrings table already implies schema changes (creating new tables), at this point you might as well update your stored procedure accordingly instead of using dynamic SQL

If that's an option then for example your query may look like

```
SELECT a.Account
FROM Database.Accounts a
 where exists (select 1 from Database.HasPhoneNumber e where e.Account = a.Account)
   and exists (select 1 from Database.HasEmaile e where e.Account = a.Account)
   and exists (select 1 from Database.HasBankAccount e where e.Account = a.Account)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample data and your sample query, you can achieve what you want without using dynamic query

```
-- sample table
declare @Accounts table
(
    Account int
)

declare @TableStrings table
(
    Table_Name  varchar(100),
    Account     int
)

-- sample data
insert into @Accounts
values (111), (222), (333), (444), (555)

insert into @TableStrings
values ('Database.HasPhoneNumber', 111), ('Database.HasPhoneNumber', 444),
       ('Database.HasEmail', 111),       ('Database.HasEmail', 222),
       ('Database.HasBankAccount', 111), ('Database.HasBankAccount', 222),
       ('Database.HasBankAccount', 555)

select  a.Account
from    @Accounts a
        inner join @TableStrings t  on  a.Account   = t.Account
group by a.Account
having count(*) = (select count(distinct Table_Name) from  @TableStrings)
```

Comment: My understanding is that there is no Account field in the TableStrings table. TableStrings just contains table names.

Comment: I am not sure, looking at OP query, it sure looks like there is one. Anyway OP does not provide a clear table schema